# Cloud functions: spread operator in object not working

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I'm trying to deploy my functions, and I have the following error:

```
> functions@ lint /Users/../functions
> eslint .


/Users/../functions/index.js
  42:40  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token ..
```

The related code is:

```
await privateRef.set({
    ...response.data, // <-- line 42
    updatedAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}, { merge: true })
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mollie/api-client": "^3.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My local node version: `v13.12.0`

It is working locally, but it seems the spread operator in object is not passing the eslint validation.. Node 10 is supporting spread operator in object ([node.green](https://node.green/)) from what I understand.

Should I adapt the eslint validation rules? I don't want to force the code to be validated if the google cloud functions environment doesn't support it..

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm struggling playing with all these eslint, babel, ecmaVersion concepts :-/

**UPDATED**

I switched the ecmaVersion from 2017 to 2019 in .eslintrc.json. No error, but is it correct? Why the ecmaVersion is initially set to 2017?

Comment: I switched the ecmaVersion from 2017 to 2019 in `.eslintrc.json`. No error, but is it correct? Why the ecmaVersion is initially set to 2017?

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, you can simply edit the question using the edit link at the bottom instead of adding a comment to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spread operator for object literals (as you are showing here) was added in ES2018.  They were not available in ES2017.  (However, spread of *array literals* was available - you might be confusing the two.)  As such, you would have to tell your tools to recognize ES2018 syntax.

The version of node in your package.json has no bearing on what eslint does.  As you've seen, eslint has its own configuration that's independent of the version of node you're targeting.  It's up to you to make sure the configurations for all your tools are in sync for your code.

See also my [blog on migrating Cloud Functions to node 10](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/migrate-your-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-js-10-d9c677933ee).